# Showing a sequence decreasing and bounded below.

Tags: analysis

I'm studying analysis, to met a difficult problem.

I want to show that a sequence $a_n$ is strictly decreasing and bounded below.

$a_n = \sum _{k=1} ^ {n-1} \frac{1}{k(n-k)} ~~for ~~~n\ge2$

first I expanded this sequence as

$ a_n = \frac{1}{n-1} + \frac{1}{2(n-2)} + \frac{1}{3(n-3)} + ...$

and doing samely to $a_{n+1}$, to show that $a_{n+1} - a_n$ is less than 0.

But I can't move forward how to show this.

Thank you for all the help.

Comment: Hint: $\frac 1 {k(n-k)}=\frac  1n (\frac  1 k +\frac  1 {n-k})$.

Comment: Very grateful!! thanks to you, I've managed to solve this problem. When time permits, I will do upload my solution. Thanks again.